# Dell Workstation PC won't boot after installing GeForce 1070 SC

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, dell-precision

I have a few new generic Dell 7820 Workstations that will be having GTX GeForce 1070 SC graphics cards installed. PC #1 has card #1 already installed (I should mention, I didn't do this installation and note sure who did). This PC works as it should. Here's the problem:

- I started setting up PC #2 with card #2 and I get no signal to the display port and the desktop does not boot up. It's as if it goes into a standby or power save mode. The PC fans will all be running with no lights on, and the graphics card will have its lights on, but no fan activity. Also no beeping sounds.
- So I tried another brand new card #3 in PC #2 and got the same results.
  I then tried another brand new PC #3 with card #2, and again with card #3, still same results.
- Next I tried the known-good card #1 inside of PC #2 and got the same results. Also trying card #2 inside of the known-good PC #1. Still same results.
- I made sure everything was seated correctly, the proper pins from the power supply were plugged into the card also. I'll also mention that the power supply is a 950W. I also tried to see if anything needed to be specially configured in the BIOS, everything was identical to the known-good PC #1. I'm not sure what else I can to troubleshoot this issue.

Any other ideas?
Let me know if I left anything out or you need more information.

Comment: To simplify this, you're saying 1 computer works with any card, and 2 computers don't?

Comment: No, the 1st computer only works with the 1st card and the 1st card only works with the 1st computer. It makes no sense to me. Putting that good card in any other computer doesn't work and putting those other 2 cards in the good computer doesn't work either.

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make sense.  I would do it all over again--even professionals make mistakes.  Pay attention to how the card is seated and the power connection being used.

Comment: Also, did you check/update the BIOS version of all three computers?  The current version is 2.4.1 and was released only a month ago.

Comment: @Jason yes, I'm going to go back and double check all the BIOS versions. These circumstances are so odd, but I will try and see if it makes a difference. Because if anything, all the cards should've worked in PC #1. Or card #1 should've worked in all 3 PCs

Comment: Are you sure the card is getting enough power?  You didn't mention the specifications of the working card (unless its just a `GTX 1060 SC`.

Comment: @Ramhound it's a GTX 1070 SC the required power is 500W or greater. These workstations have 950W. And the other cards are identical to the first card, part numbers and all.

Comment: @Ramhound The standard power supply in a Precision 7820 is 950W per the owner's manual, and it's intended to be used with graphics cards with higher power consumption than a GTX 1070.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out! After searching all day on the EVGA forums, someone was able to help me. He told me a about a known issue with some of the series cards working with 1.3/1.4 DP. Here's what was said:

"DP 1.3 / 1.4 monitor could blank screens on boot until the OS loads or Hang on Boot

RE:  NVIDIA Graphics Firmware Update Tool.

Without the update, systems that are connected to a DisplayPort 1.3 / 1.4 monitor could experience blank screens on boot until the operating system loads, or could experience a hang on boot.

NVIDIA has created a downloadable tool which will detect whether the firmware update is needed, and if needed, give the user the option to update it.

This update only applies to the graphics cards listed.
For desktop systems, please follow the link below to download the NVIDIA Graphics Firmware Update Tool.
http://www.nvidia.com/object/nv-uefi-update.html"

So after I plugged in an HDMI cord, I finally got a good boot up and I was able to run the firmware update tool and it did need the update. After the update, the DP works perfectly!

Thanks everyone for all your help!